# How to clean , from a given string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

I have data like this.

```
var abc =",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,paul,2000,12sc21,logan,123,21sdf34,vfsarwe,456456,32fd23";
abc = abc.split(",");

let stub={};
        var results=[];
        var key=["name","value","acc"];
        var i=0;
        var j=0;

        for( var i = 0 ; i <abc.length - 1;i++){
           stub[key[j]=abc[i];
           j++
           if(j==3){
               results.push(stub);
               stub={};
               j=0;
    }
}
         abc = results;
```

> I would like to get those values arranges in form of array of object having those 3 keys:

output should be:

```
abc = [{"name": "paul", "value": "2000","acc":"12sc21"},{"name":"logan","value":"123","acc":"21sdf34"},{"name":"vfsarwe","value":"456456","acc":"32fd23"}];
```

but not able to get the desired output. this output only comes when string don't have ,,,,,, in starting. But the data i'm getting is sometimes having ,,,,, in stating.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: Is the number of those empty entries always a multiple of 3?

Comment: yes entries are always in the multiple of 3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
abc.replace(/,+/g, ',').replace(/^,|,$/g, '').split(',');
```

The regEx replaces removes the data that you are not interested in before performing the split.

or

```
abc.split(',').filter(Boolean);
```

The filter(Boolean) will remove the items from the array that [could be the equivalent of false](http://www.devign.me/javascript-tip-remove-falsy-items-out-of-an-array) once the array has been instantiated.

**EDIT**:

```
var abc =",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,paul,2,000,12sc21,logan,123,21sdf34,vfsarwe,456456,32fd23";
var array = abc.replace(/,+/g, ',').replace(/^,|,$/g, '').split(/,([0-9,]+),/);
array = array.filter(Boolean).reduce(function(acc, item) {
    if (item.match(/^[0-9,]+$/)) {
      acc.push(item);
    } else {
      acc = acc.concat(item.split(','));
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: This has something of a problem in that it doesn't lead to the required solution (`abc = [{"name": "paul", "value": "2000","acc":"12sc21"}...];`). Or am I misreading the question?

Comment: I believe that this code only replaces the second line of the code in the question, from that point the original code should still work.

Comment: @DavidThomas the title say to clean `,` I've assume that this was the question.

Comment: I think it will not work if that value 2000 is in the form of 2,000 and 456456 in the form of 456,456. Is there any way that if this kind of value come it will treat 2,000 as 2,000 only not as 2    000

Comment: @shalabh you can try to use `abc.split(/,(?!\d)/).filter(Boolean);` it will split on comma if it's not followed by a number.

Comment: @jcubic i tried it but the it is giving output likt this: 0: {…}
​​
acc: "vfsarwe,456,456,32fd23"
​​
name: "paul,2,000,12sc21"
​​
value: "logan,123,21sdf34"

Comment: @shalabh updated the code that will handle 2,000 it's more complex but it produce clean array. On top of that you will need to split into objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `abc.replace(/(^[,\s]+)/g, '')` to remove leading commas or whitespace from the String. Your `for` loop is also not running for long enough; it is looping until there is only one element left in the Array and then stopping.

Change

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < abc.length-1; i++)
```

To

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < abc.length; i++)
```

```js
var abc =",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,paul,2000,12sc21,logan,123,21sdf34,vfsarwe,456456,32fd23";
abc = abc.replace(/(^[,\s]+)|([,\s]+$)/g, '').split(",");

let stub={};
        var results=[];
        var key=["name","value","acc"];
        var i=0;
        var j=0;

        for(var i = 0 ; i < abc.length; i++){
           stub[key[j]]=abc[i];
           j++
           if(j==3){
               results.push(stub);
               stub={};
               j=0;
    }
}
abc = results;
console.log(abc);
```

Comment: thanks for the code looks fine. I will test it with my code now.

Comment: I think it will not work if that value 2000 is in the form of 2,000 and 456456 in the form of 456,456.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace(/^\,+/, '')` to remove all leading commas, then split by comma to get an `array`, then loop over this `array` using `3` as step and construct your results:

```
var abc = ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,paul,2000,12sc21,logan,123,21sdf34,vfsarwe,456456,32fd23";
var arr = abc.replace(/^\,+/, '').split(",");
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 3) {
  results.push({
    "name": arr[i],
    "value": arr[i + 1],
    "acc": arr[i + 2]
  });
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var abc = ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,paul,2000,12sc21,logan,123,21sdf34,vfsarwe,456456,32fd23";
var arr = abc.replace(/^\,+/, '').split(",");
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 3) {
  results.push({
    "name": arr[i],
    "value": arr[i + 1],
    "acc": arr[i + 2]
  });
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: I think it will not work if that value 2000 is in the form of 2,000 and 456456 in the form of 456,456. Is there any way that if this kind of value come it will treat 2,000 as 2,000 only not as 2    000

Comment: @shalabh No, this way it won't be working, in that case how can you separate `2000,12sc21`?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with splitting your data on `,`. You can then split the data in to chunks of 3, and from there map each chunk to a dict.

```js
var data = ",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,paul,2000,12sc21,logan,123,21sdf34,vfsarwe,456456,32fd23";
var split = data.split(",");
var chunked = [];
while (split.length) {
    chunked.push(split.splice(0,3));
}
var res = chunked.map((i) => {
    if (!i[0] || !i[1] || !i[2]) {
        return null;
    }
    return {
      name: i[0],
      value: i[1],
      acc: i[2]
    };
}).filter((i) => i !== null);
console.log(res);
```